# How to read html string

Tags: android, html, html-table, html-parsing

I implemented ccavenue integration in my android app

ccavenue returns html string

I need to read html body content and table rows from that string

Below is html string

```
<head><head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>Response Handler</title>
         </head>
         <body>


            <center>
                <font size="4" color="blue"><b>Response Page</b></font>
                <table border="1">

                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>merchant_param5 </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>merchant_param4 </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>merchant_param3 </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_name </td>
                            <td> Amit </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>merchant_param2 </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>status_message </td>
                            <td> Payment failed due to a technical error with the bank. Please retry after some time. </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>merchant_param1 </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_city </td>
                            <td> Nashik </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>amount </td>
                            <td> 1.0 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>order_status </td>
                            <td> Failure </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_country </td>
                            <td> India </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>response_code </td>
                            <td> 0 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_address </td>
                            <td> Nashik </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_notes </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>discount_value </td>
                            <td> 0.0 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>retry </td>
                            <td> N </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_zip </td>
                            <td> 422005 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_country </td>
                            <td> India </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_tel </td>
                            <td> 9404005390 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>failure_message </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>order_id </td>
                            <td> 6355706 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>bank_ref_no </td>
                            <td> null </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_address </td>
                            <td> Nashik </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>status_code </td>
                            <td> null </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_state </td>
                            <td> Maharashtra </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>payment_mode </td>
                            <td> Wallet </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>vault </td>
                            <td> N </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_state </td>
                            <td> Maharashtra </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>offer_type </td>
                            <td> null </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>bin_country </td>
                            <td>  </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_name </td>
                            <td> Amit </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>offer_code </td>
                            <td> null </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>tracking_id </td>
                            <td> 106246806219 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_city </td>
                            <td> Nashik </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>trans_date </td>
                            <td> 01/07/2017 20:27:58 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_zip </td>
                            <td> 422005 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>delivery_tel </td>
                            <td> 9404005390 </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>currency </td>
                            <td> INR </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>eci_value </td>
                            <td> null </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>card_name </td>
                            <td> Paytm </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>billing_email </td>
                            <td> desale.amit@gmail.com </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>mer_amount </td>
                            <td> 1.0 </td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody></table>
            </center>


         </body></head>
```

I need to parse above html string

how to parse this string

please suggest

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JSOUP`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsoup160jar.htm) to fetch your data as `String`

1.) Get the string as Document using `Jsoup.parse(your_string)`

2.) Get all nodes using `document.getAllElements()` as Elements

3.) Traverse the elements and use `ownText()` function to fetch data

```
    Document document=Jsoup.parse(your_response);
    Elements elements = document.getAllElements();
    for (Element element : elements) {
        String data =element.ownText();
        // some strings are empty so avoid them
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(data);               
        }
    }
```

output

```
Response Handler
Response Page
merchant_param5
merchant_param4
merchant_param3
billing_name
Amit
... data
... more data
desale.amit@gmail.com
mer_amount
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsop](https://jsoup.org/download) lib or [Htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)